# Is this an appropriate database design if I wanted to audit my table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

It's my first time creating an audit log for a PoS WPF application and was wondering on how exactly do I implement an auditing system because it seems like each option available has its ups and downs. So far from reading numerous articles/threads, I've narrowed down a few common practices on audit logs:

**1. Triggers** - Unfortunately, due to the nature of my app, I can't make use of triggers as it has no way of knowing which user has done the action. So what I did instead was to create a Stored Procedure which will handle the customer insert along with the customer log insert and its details. The Customer_Id will be provided by the application when using the Stored Procedure.

**2. Have an old and new value** - My initial plan was to only include the latter since I can reference its old value with the new value from the row before it but storing the the old and new value seemed more sensible, complexity-wise.

**3. Use a separate database for the log / 4. Foreign Keys** - This is probably my main concern, if I decide to use a separate database for the audit table, then I couldn't setup foreign keys for the customer and employee involved.

I created a mock-up erd with a master-detail table result to be shown on the wpf app to display the log to an admin and would really like your thoughts on possible problems that may arise (There's also an employee table but I forgot to put it):

https://ibb.co/dheaNK

**Here's a few info that might be of help:**

1. The database will reside together with the wpf app, which is a single computer.
2. The amount of customers will be less than 1000.
3. The amount of regular employees will be 3.
4. The amount of admins will be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [CDC Change Data Capture](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/change-data-capture.aspx) on SQL Server database for a specific table
This will enable you to collect all data changes on the database table logged in special tables.
You can also refer to [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) too

Here is a list of DML commands and how data changes are logged in the CDC table created for the source database table

[image]

What is good about CDC is it comes default with SQL Server and you don't have to do anything for logging. The only requirement is SQL Server Agent should be running so that the changes can be reflected on log table.

Comment: How would I go about knowing which employee committed the change? On the top of my head since there will be a login table, should I use that as basis for the user who committed the change if the change was done between their login/logout datetime?

Comment: Oh and I've also thought about adding another column 'reason' with predetermined options so the admin would have a better idea for the reason behind the create/edit/enable/disable, how would that be incorporated within the cdc?

Comment: The CDC log table is a reflection of the source table in fact. If you add those columns in your Login table, you will see those values also in the CDC table too

Comment: In fact, for login tracking you can also use SQL Server Audit features http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-login-auditing.aspx  . Of course in such a case you won't be able to provide additional information like reason, etc.